# Can you please provide one fully solved gradient boosting regression numerical example (not python code)

Tags: machine-learning, regression, ensemble-learning, ensemble, natural-gradient-boosting

Can you please provide one fully solved gradient boost regression numerical example (not Python code).

Comment: This question was posted twice: [Can you please provide one fully solved Support vector regression numerical example (not python code)?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/123680/can-you-please-provide-one-fully-solved-support-vector-regression-numerical-exam)

Comment: @noe not really the same question actually.

Comment: Please explain what you understand, provide your work, explain what are your difficulties...